# What qualifies as a "precision loadout weapon"?

Tags: halo-4

Several challenges have asked for kills with "precision loadout weapons"? What weapons qualify and do you need to start with them?

[image: To Be Precise]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A "Precision Loadout Weapon" is a precision rifle-type weapon that you can spawn with.

There are 4 weapons that meet this criteria: DMR, Battle Rifle, Covenant Carbine and Light Rifle.

If you want to quickly complete this challenge, I would recommend playing SWAT, since you have to start with a precision weapon and enemies die with a single headshot.

Also, keep in mind if the playlist has you spawn with a precision weapon that is **normally** a pick-up weapon, this still counts.  For example, in Team Snipers you spawn with a Sniper Rifle; this **does** count towards these type of challenges.

Here is a forum thread about challenges that touches on this topic: [Xbox360 Achievements - Halo 4 Challenges Thread](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=398216&page=9)

Comment: In addition, any playlist that spawned you with a precision rifle (i.e. Sniper Rifle) would also count. This type of challege was easy to get when Team Snipers was in rotation (but has since been removed :( )