# What qualifies as an “automatic loadout weapon”?

Tags: halo-4

Similar to [the "precision loadout weapon" challenges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/94629/21177), several challenges have asked for kills with "**automatic** loadout weapons"? Are all non-"precision" starter weapons automatic? What weapons qualify and do you need to start with them?

[image: Fully Automated]

Comment: In general, an automatic weapon is one that will continue to fire with a single trigger-pull, so yes, that's pretty much all the non-precision starters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The automatic loadout weapons are the automatic weapons that you can put in loadouts: the Assault Rifle, the Storm Rifle, and the Suppressor. You do not need to start with them to get credit for the achievement.